# Inherit stage using cusom ftl file in Magnolia 4.5.3

Tags: freemarker, magnolia

I’m attempting to write a freemarker template for stages which checks if a stage is defined for this page, and if not, tries to inherit the stage from its parent page.
Standard inheritance (like it’s default e.g. for footers) doesn’t work for me, because users should still be able to define different stages for subpages if desired.

I already have a template that’s working in Magnolia 4.4, but this is not usable in 4.5 because of various changes in the templating API. So I tried to adapt it to 4.5: I’m using the cmsfn.inherit() function to find parent content and then access this content’s stage, but I keep getting errors (saying that it’s not specified).

My Template:

```
<div id="stage" style="color: white;">
  [#if content??]
    [@cms.component content=content /]
  [#else]
    [#assign inheritedContent = cmsfn.inherit(cmsfn.content(state.mainContent.@handle)) /]
      [#if cmsfn.isEditMode()]
        Inherited content: ${inheritedContent}
      [/#if]
      [@cms.component content=inheritedContent.stage /]
  [/#if]
</div><!-- end stage -->
```

Error Message:

```
The 'content' parameter was passed but not or wrongly specified. The problematic instruction:
----------
==> user-directive cms.component [on line 17, column 17 in ***/pages/home/inheritStage.ftl]
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm too late with the answer but if someone else finds this:
the way content is inherited in magnolia cms 4.5 changed a bit - now it's done a bit differently using prototype configuration:

in your author instance go to templating kit->site configuration then go to templates->prototype->area->YOURAREA and add a new content node called "inheritance" and create node data for it.

node data:

components - this can be either "all" (all components are inherited), "filtered" (all components that have inheritance property set to true are inherited) or "none" (is self-explanatory)
enabled - self-explanatory

also if you decide to inherit "filtered" components don't forget to add inheritance dialog option to the component in question

if you want to see a working example look at "extras" prototype.

Comment: Yes, I know this option, but in this case, you cannot edit the inherited content on a sub-site, and that's  what we wanted... We did it now by implementing the inheritance manually in the areas modelClass (in Java). Not the nicest solution, but it works.
But anyway, I gave you +1 for your effort... ;-)